# Bind Dns server stopped working after Ip change

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, dns-hosting

So, I have changed my server location from US to Lithuania and my server stopped working

I can connect to my db and virtualmin but only with my IP

[image: zone]

/etc/bind/named.conf:

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
key rndc-key {
    algorithm hmac-sha256;
    secret "....";
    };
controls {
    inet 127.0.0.1 port 953 allow { 127.0.0.1; } keys { rndc-key; };
    };
```

/etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
    // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
    // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

    // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
    // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
    // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
    // the all-0's placeholder.

    // forwarders {
    //  0.0.0.0;
    // };

    //========================================================================
    // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
    // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
    //========================================================================
    dnssec-validation auto;

    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    //dnssec-enable yes;
};
```

Comment: How do you diagnose that it stopped working?

Comment: First of all, the site doesn't open, second of all using a port checker and a DNS checker

Answer (score 2):

Your name servers are:

```
Nameserver: ns1.goodjobs.ro
Nameserver: ns2.goodjobs.ro
```

As they are within the same domain, they need [*glue records*](https://serverfault.com/a/681644/274176) at the parent `.ro` zone, but they are missing:

```
goodjobs.ro.        86400   IN  NS  ns1.goodjobs.ro.
goodjobs.ro.        86400   IN  NS  ns2.goodjobs.ro.
/usr/bin/dig: couldn't get address for 'ns1.goodjobs.ro': no more
```

You can set the glue records through your registrar.

Furthermore, you need at least two name servers. The screenshot of your zone shows you are trying to point both `ns1` & `ns2` to the same IP address. Get a secondary name server or use an external DNS service altogether.